# Safari no longer defaults to typing in address bar. Why?

Tags: safari

I recently deleted cookies and deleted my AdBlocker for Safari. Since then, things have been acting weird, e.g. websites open slowly, my homepage was set to Yahoo, etc.

Previously, when I would open a new tab, the cursor would be in the address bar. Any typing I would do would start there. Now, I must manually click the address bar, or use the `Command + L` shortcut to go there.

That's a pain. How could I reset this? I see nothing in Safari's Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system could have been infected with adware and/or malware. See this [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987) on how to remove adware.

For malware, I have relied on Sophos' free [Antivirus for Mac](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx) for several years. I use it on my home machines, and my school uses it enterprise-wide on all Mac and Windows desktops, laptops and servers.

Comment: You're right. It looks like my Mac was infected by some browser redirect malware.

Answer (score -1):

Under Safari -> Preferences -> Search ->

Uncheck “Include Safari Suggestions”

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your answer doesn't address the question,  Please be sure to fully read the question before you attempt to answer.  You can read [answer] for more info. - From Review -